# Migrate single site to Multisites with plugins, cPanel and already working subdomains

Tags: multisite, subdomains, shared-hosting

I've read almost all similar questions suggested related to multisites, cPanel, subdomains, etc. but have not found a solution for what I want to setup.

I have a working WordPress site with ssl, WooCommerce, etc., hosted with cPanel. I've also some subdomains working with another applications and would like to setup a Multisite with subdomains.

I've read I should add a * "wildcard" subdomain pointing to public_html and that it should be added at bottom of the list

My questions are

1) Will I loose settings/info/data when WordPress tells me to disable my plugins for enabling/installing a Multisite Network?

2) What can I do with the * wildcard sub-domain to listed at bottom without contacting the hosting company? Is this requisite a must for all to work?

3) Can I also have another domain added in cPanel and use it for mapping one of the sub-sites to it? Which plugin is being used for this?

Thanks a lot for any guidance you can give

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No data/settings/options are lost, very rarely deleted, when deactivating plugins.

2) You do not need a wildcard subdomain unless you want to let visitors register for/create their own site/blog. But it doesn't hurt to have it. Else: explicitly add all subdomains in zone file.

3) In case you want several domains to map to the same site (special cases) you need [Domain Mapping plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/). WP Multisite does not need domain mapping to respond to different domains for each site. (This is a common misunderstanding, though.)

All sudomains that shall be served by the multisite must point to the same root folder as WP is installed in. Use "subdomain install" in WP-config for both subdomains and separate domains.